# Oracle : How to have only one row active in a table?

Tags: oracle

I have an Oracle table with a field Named **Active**.
This field has a unique constraint, so only one row will be marked as Active.

Is there any way in the **database** layer to keep only one row active when adding a new row or updating old ones ?

Example

Current State of Table

```
ID        Active
----------------
1         yes
```

A new active row is added :

New State of the table

```
ID        Active
----------------
1         No
2         Yes
```

The row 1 is updated with Active = Yes

```
ID        Active
----------------
1         Yes
2         No
```

Of course I can not update the table using a trigger when a new row is beign inserted.

Does anyone have an idea on how to do that please ?

Comment: :If it is a unique constraint ,then it will not allow you to insert or update ACTIVE column with yes ,if it is already present .Still i dint understand your requirement ,the Active values get interchanged on update ,is this is your requirement?

Comment: Exactly this is my need : Active values get interchanged on update or insert. Any idea please ?

Comment: :It will be better ,if your write a small stored procedure,and whenever you need to update or insert call that procedure .I think this is not possible through trigger .

Comment: And when this procedure can be executed ? Theoretically it should be done before inserting a new row, but Oracle won't like this

Comment: You can write statement level trigger to achieve that.

Comment: Do you have any example please ?

Comment: Create a statement level `before update or insert` trigger to set all existing rows to NO, then only the row that you will update or insert will remain YES.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to call this procedure with valid values as input parameter

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE t416493.set_tab
    (
     p_id IN tab.id%TYPE
    ,p_active_flag IN tab.active%TYPE
    ,p_dml_type    IN VARCHAR2
    )

    IS 

    CURSOR check_flag_exists
    IS 
    SELECT id 
    FROM tab
    WHERE active = p_active_flag;

    v_id tab.id%TYPE;
    v_active_flag VARCHAR2(3);

    BEGIN

        OPEN check_flag_exists;
          FETCH check_flag_exists INTO v_id;
            IF check_flag_exists%FOUND THEN 

              IF  p_active_flag ='Yes' THEN
                  v_active_flag :='No';
              ELSE
                 v_active_flag :='Yes';
              END IF;

                UPDATE tab
                 SET  active = v_active_flag
                WHERE id =v_id; 

            END IF; 
         CLOSE check_flag_exists;  

         IF p_dml_type ='INSERT' THEN 
          INSERT INTO tab 
           (id
           ,active
           )
           VALUES
           (p_id
           ,p_active_flag
           );
         ELSIF p_dml_type ='UPDATE' THEN
           UPDATE tab
           SET active =p_active_flag
           WHERE id =v_id; 
         END IF;  

    END set_tab;
```

You need to call your proc like this as shown below:

begin

```
 set_tab
       (
         p_id =>2
        ,p_active_flag =>'Yes'
        ,p_dml_type   =>'INSERT'
        );

end;
/
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. When this procedure should be called ? Which event should triggers it ?

Comment: Gaurav +1 for the solution, good idea. However was wondering whether the same could be achieved using triggers?

Comment: @Polppan:I thought about creating a trigger initially ,but that would be recursive call on the same table indefinitely, that's why i avoid using a trigger.Even i am eager how it can be achieved with trigger

Comment: @ThomasCarlton:It will be called every time you need to insert or update in your table .And if some other method try to insert or update this table,then it will obviously throws a unique constraint error .So  we are safe on the other side when direct inserts happens

Comment: I mean after which event this should be called ? Should it be called in a trigger (Before or After Insert) ? Should it be called manually from the application layer ?

Comment: (1) there's no need to query the table before doing an update. (2) due to a lack of serialization, if there are multiple concurrent sessions, it will be possible to use this procedure to create multiple conflicting active records.